# How to convert byte[] back to Barcode in ZXing

Tags: zxing

`ZXing.Result` obtained from `ZXing.BarcodeReader` provides a property of `RawBytes` of `byte[]`. However, I have tried but been unable to find a function in `ZXing.BarcodeWriter` which accepts `byte[]` as its argument.

I want to have a barcode from `ZXing.BarcodeWriter` which is exactly the same as that `ZXing.BarcodeReader` reads.

> say, a barcode is known as Code 128,
>
> `BarcodeReader` gives `RawBytes` starts with 3 bytes, `105`, `102`, `42`,
>
> which means [Start Code C], [FNC 1], [42] in Code 128,
>
> which means the barcode starts with 2 digits `4`, `2`.

The major reason to find such a function is that meta-data is lost if a barcode is converted to `string` and converted back.

> `string` only represents `4` and `2`, and [Start Code C] and [FNC 1] are lost.

Is there a function for that? You may assume the barcode format is known.

<sub>I am using ZXing.NET, but I suppose the functions are similar across different platforms.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

It dependents on the barcode type, if a encode method with a byte array parameter is available. For the Aztec-Barcode you can use the class com.google.zxing.aztec.encoder.Encoder which provides the method:

```
public static AztecCode encode(byte[] data)
```

The Encoder class of the QR-Code for example doesn't provide a encode method with a byte[].

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not BarcodeWriter which accepts a byte array.
But you can set an option which interprets the GS1 symbology.

```
var reader = new BarcodeReader { Options = new DecodingOptions { AssumeGS1 = true } };
```

The barcode reader will now convert the FNC1 codeword to a string representation in the result, in your case "]C142". The FNC1 representation "]C1" isn't very intuitive but it is defined in the GS1 spec for Code 128 5.4.6.4. Every following FNC1 codeword is translated to the group separator character (GS / 0x1D / (char)29).

The barcode writer on the other hand uses only the group separator character.
That means if you want to generate the same barcode from the result string you have to replace the leading "]C1" with "(char)29".